# Label color the same as bubble fill using ggrepel

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I have a bubble chart and I'm using ggrepel to avoid overlapping labels.

Reproducible example:

```
library(randomcoloR)
n <- nrow(iris)
palette <- unname(distinctColorPalette(n))


(p <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length,
             y=Sepal.Width,
             label = Species,
             color = palette)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values=palette)
)


(r <-
    p + geom_point(
      aes(size = Petal.Length*Petal.Width),
      pch = 21,
      show.legend = FALSE,
      fill = palette
    ) +
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 30)) +
    geom_text_repel(segment.color = "orange",
                    nudge_y = 0.05,
                    angle        = 0,
                    vjust        = -5,
                    segment.size = 0.2) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
)
```

The issue is I want the label the same color the bubble but I'm getting the color of the circle border instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `color` and `fill` should be inside aesthetics `aes()`, then `ggrepel` will recognise them. I mean `ggrepel` use that one which specified in `aes`
I've rewrite your code a bit:

```
library(randomcoloR)
library(ggrepel)
n <- nrow(iris)
palette <- unname(distinctColorPalette(n))


iris %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length,
               y=Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point(
      aes(size = Petal.Length*Petal.Width,
          fill = palette,
          color = palette),
      alpha = .7,
      pch = 21,
      show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 30)) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = Species,
                        color = palette),
                    segment.color = "orange",
                    nudge_y = 0.05,
                    angle        = 0,
                    vjust        = -5,
                    segment.size = 0.2) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]